# Issues using Amazon SES as relay with sendmail [530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first]

Tags: redhat, smtp, sendmail, amazon-ses

I'm trying to get our old rhel3 servers relaying out with sendmail 8.13.1

I have followed amazon's guide here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sendmail.html

But it seems the server does not authenticate correctly with amazon, the bounced back email states a "<<< 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first" - as in something is not happing in the correct order.

My sendmail.mc: http://pastebin.com/k0Y1s6pZ

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The root bounce: http://pastebin.com/t22G4F69

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resoved after we discovered that the EDGE Cisco ASA did some packet inspection on the SMTP steam, and removing the STARTTLS completely

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your sendmail must issue `STARTTLS` (convert connection into encrypted connection) before issuing AUTH.

AFAIR sendmail tries to use STARTTLS by default.  Have you installed openssl package/rpm on your host?

Comment: Hi, OpenSSL is installed correctly yes